# Power series for $(a+x)^{-1}$

Tags: calculus, power-series

Is it possible to write the following expression in terms of power series?

$$ (a+x)^{-1}=\sum\limits_{k =  - \infty }^\infty  {{b_k}{x^k}} $$

where $0 < a < 1$ and $0 < x < 1$.

Comment: This problem is covered in virtually all calculus classes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series

Comment: In addition to the solutions, if $a<x<1$ you can write $$\frac{1}{a+x}=\frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{1+a/x}$$and do a similar expansion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be turned into [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum):

$$\frac{1}{a+x} = \frac{1}{a} \cdot \frac{1}{1-\left(-\frac{x}{a}\right)} = \frac{1}{a}\cdot\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(-\frac{x}{a}\right)^k$$

which converges whenever $|x| < |a|$.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the general binomial series (converging for $|x| < 1$):

$$(1+x)^\alpha = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1) \ldots (\alpha-k+1)}{k!}x^k.$$

Hence,

$$(a+x)^{-1} = a^{-1}(1 + x/a)^{-1}  = a^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{-1(-2) \ldots (-k)}{k!}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^k\\ = a^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^k,$$

converging for $|x| < |a|.$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$$
$$\frac{1}{1+x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^n$$
$$\frac{1}{1+x/a}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^n$$
$$\frac{1}{a+x}=\frac1a\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^n$$

Convergent for $$\left|\frac{x}{a}\right|<1\implies x<a$$

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, there is this geometric series:
$$
\frac{1}{a+x} = \frac{1}{x}\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{a}{x}}\right)
= \frac{1}{x}\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\left(\frac{a}{x}\right)^k
=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}(-1)^{n+1}a^{-n-1}x^n
$$
with convergence for $|x|>a$.